# Failed to understand how to use glm::unProject (OpenGL 4.3)

Tags: opengl, c++, glm

Situation:
I use OpenGL 4.3, FreeGLUT 3.0, and GLM library.

Let say i have a simple 2D object (a ball) and it moves accordingly to the simple equations:

x = x_0 + v_0 * t * cosf(alpha);

y = y_0 + v_0 * t * sinf(alpha) - 0.5 * g * t * t;

So i can be sure what are x and y in every time step.

My GLUT mouse callback is:

```
void onMouse(int button, int state, int mx, int my) {
    if (state != GLUT_DOWN)
        return;
    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 10.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
    projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f*640 / 480, 0.1f, 10.0f);      
    glm::vec4 viewport = glm::vec4(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glm::vec3 wincoord = glm::vec3(mx, 480 - my, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 objcoord = glm::unProject(wincoord, view, projection, viewport);
}
```

So, when the ball moves and i click on it, i suppose to get (objcoord.x,  objcoord.y) very close to the center of the ball (x,y).

Coordinates of the ball itself (x,y) are calculated correctly. But when i click on the ball, (objcoord.x, objcoord.y) are not even close to the (x,y).
I always get very small values like (0.0012, 0.099) wherever i click on the screen. 
I feel that it might be due to some Z (depth) issues, but i don't have enough knowledge here and ask for help now.

Answer (score -1):

try using something >= your near (i.e. >= 0.1) for your window_z instead of 0?

```
glm::vec3 wincoord = glm::vec3(mx, 480 - my, /**/0.1f/**/);
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If it's an answer please explain what problem this is solving, and how it solves it.